# Arbitrary changes to the terrain in the game that was previously modified by the player

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I want built big floor on terrain where was hill before. So i did it:

[image: what i built]

but after I went far away and came back i found part of hill back in my floor:

[image: what did i find when i came back]

Can anybody help with prevent this bug? Game version is A21. I am playing single player, navzgame map.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having an issue with terrain regeneration in the game. If so here are some tips that may help you:

1. Identify the terrain blocks that are reappearing.
2. Place a building block where the phantom terrain appears. This
   should cause the floating blocks to disappear and prevent them from
   reappearing.

Additionally, if you’re seeing red indicators on blocks you’re trying to place, it might be due to the game being confused by the phantom terrain. The stability indication can sometimes be incorrect, but there’s an internal ticket for this issue, which may be resolved in future updates.

Comment: THX for reply. Yes, that's exactly what I did. When I saw this phenomenon for the first time, I started building a floor to make sure that I had removed all the blocks and knew where. The original intention was just to level the hill... I did see the red indicators - and indeed, I thought it was a stability indicator, but since no collapse occurred, I took it easy. I have encountered phantom terrain in other cases as well, such as blocks where I can't place anything. As I tried to 'mine' something invisible that might be there - I couldn't find anything, and these blocks are simply empty...

Comment: The red indicators you’re seeing are likely due to the game’s confusion with the phantom terrain, which is a known bug in the A21 version of the game.

The inability to place anything in certain blocks, despite them appearing empty, is also a part of this bug. The game’s developers are aware of these issues, and an internal ticket has been created to address them. https://community.7daystodie.com/a21-bugs-main/confirmed/indestructable-terrain-blocks-r584/

Comment: In the meantime, here are a few tips you can try:

Sometimes, game files can become corrupted or incomplete. Validating them through the game’s launcher can fix issues that aren’t related to your saved files.
If you notice certain areas are more prone to these bugs, it might be best to avoid building there until the bug is fixed.
Ensure that you’re running the latest version of the game, as updates often contain bug fixes.